# Include external js in enduro.js CMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mime, enduro.js

I'm trying to use enduro.js but i need to include an external js file to my index.hbs putting a script tag after body, just like a normal html file.

```
<script src="/assets/js/popper.js"></script>
```

This just says me in chrome console

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:3000/assets/js/popper.js' because
>   its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled.

Can someone help me?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
  <script src="/assets/js/popper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer... I already tryed but with no luck... nothing changed

Comment: Removing the leading slash in the src should fix it `<script src="assets/js/popper.js"></script>`

Comment: Still no luck at all :(